# Why do some hooks not work inside class context?

Tags: hooks, actions, oop

I'm pretty stumped on this one. I'm using add_action inside my plugin class to do certain things- add scripts & styles to the head, wp_ajax, etc. Here's the actions, in the __construct:

```
function __construct(){
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'sph_admin_menu'));
    add_action('sph_header', array($this, 'sph_callback'));
    add_action('sph_header_items', array($this, 'sph_default_menu'), 1);
    add_action('sph_header_items', array($this, 'sph_searchform'), 2);
    add_action('sph_header_items', array($this, 'sph_social'), 3);

    //Below here they don't work. I have to call these outside of the class (but I need class variables within the functions)
    add_action('wp_print_styles', array(&$this, 'sph_stylesheets'));
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', array(&$this, 'sph_scripts'));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_list', array(&$this, 'le_add_to_list'));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_to_list', array(&$this, 'le_add_to_list'));
    add_action('init', array(&$this, 'register_menu'));
}
```

Anybody ever come across something like this? I'd really like to know how to use said hooks from within a class- it's so messy having actions outside the class!

Comment: were do you create an instance of this class? ex: `$my_plugin = new MYClass();` since I've used these same hooks from within a class with no problems.

Comment: Additionally, make sure that functions serving as the hooks have `public` visibility.

Comment: Bainternet yeah I am. 
@Joseph that could be it. can construct be public?
Cheers

Comment: @Harley - bainternet was asking *where* do you create an instance.

Comment: @Harley if you do not include a visibility modifier, it is automatically set to public. I was referring to the actual function the performs whatever action is being hooked.

Comment: bainternet's first comment is the answer

Comment: it's not enough to define a class, you have to create instances of it with the `new` keyword and assign them to variables. E.g. `class MyObj {}` doesn't do anything, no matter how many actions I put in its constructor, it isn't until I write `$obj = new MyObj()` that any code runs. Bainternet was asking where you put the `new`/used the class to create an object

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes certain hooks need to be fired at certain times. Example, some hooks need to be fired upon **init**.

Add this to your `__construct()`

```
add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
```

Then add this function, which will contain all hooks that need to be fired upon **init**.

```
public function init(){
    add_action('hook_name', array(&$this, 'your_method_name'));
    add_action('hook_name', array(&$this, 'your_method_name'));
    add_action('hook_name', array(&$this, 'your_method_name'));
    add_action('hook_name', array(&$this, 'your_method_name'));
}
```

Another Example:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {

    add_action( 'hook_name', 'function_name', 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'hook_name', __NAMESPACE__ . '\namespaced_function_name', 10 );
    add_action( 'hook_name', '\specific\namespace\function_name', 5 );

}, 1 );
```

You will want to read about the hooks and when they are fired. So you know when and where to trigger your actions. [Plugin API/Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old question, but in case anyone is looking for an answer, I had a similar issue. I had a class

```
class Plugin{
  function __construct(){
    add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
  }

  function init(){
    // code...
  }
}
```

Plugin::init() was never getting called. I then realized my mistake. To instantiate the class I was doing this:

```
if(class_exists('Plugin')){
    add_action("init", "plugin_init");
    function socialsports_init() {
      global $plugin;
      $plugin = new Plugin;
    }
}
```

To fix it, I just changed the instantiation code to:

```
if(class_exists('Plugin')){
    add_action("init", "plugin_init");
    function socialsports_init() {
      global $plugin;
      $plugin = new Plugin;
      $plugin->init();
    }
}
```

The other option would be to use a different hook in the constructor:

```
function __construct(){
  add_action('wp_loaded', array(&$this, 'init'));
}
```

Or an earlier hook in the instantiation:

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", "plugin_init");
```